# Why there's additional space at the beginning of EditText

Tags: android

I have a login view with two EditText for email and password and one TextView to indicate any errors. I set the start margin of each view as same value. However, I noticed that the starting positions of text in my TextView and my EditText are not aligned to each other. There's 1-2 pixels additional padding before the text in EditText view. Why do I get this additional padding? Can I adjust it or remove it so that my TextView and EditText align to each other?

[Screenshot of the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DFzo.png)

My code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    tools:context=".ui.login.LoginActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_indicator"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:text="Invalid password"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/password"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/login_button"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

padding of the line is because the standard EditText background
"?android:editTextBackground" , and padding of text inside is because the default padding which i think "4dp" , so if you put "android:paddingLeft="0dp"" the text will be align to textview , but the padding of the line will still

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know whether there's a way to remove the padding of underline as well? Or do I have to change the background to a custom one?

Comment: yes i think you have to create a custom background drawable that has no padding , or in your "android:layout_marginStart="24dp"" change the value to "20dp"